# Regular Expression Exclude Specific Files

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a regular expression that redirects any files in the folder "/downloads" to a PHP script which then serves the file (alongwith other stuff). However, I'd like to have some PHP files in there that I can view, and not have them download (also a security problem, obviously). However, I don't know that much about regular expression. I'm looking nito it, but not getting it right :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect any file coming in to the downloads manager
RewriteRule ^(.+\.*) /downloads?file=$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The only thing I can find so far that could work is `RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$ - [L]`. However, this does not work. If anyone could quickly explain this, or give me something tha twill work, that would be great!
Also, as you may have figured out this redirects to the index.php of the /downloads folder. If you could explain why it doesn't download itself, that would be great. It does download when I go to downloads/index.php, but not simply /downloads. Not required information to get it working, but would like to know :)
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: In your `RewriteRule`, do you mean `.+\.*` or `.+\..*`? The first looks for any string ending in 0 or more periods, while the second looks for any string specifically with a period in it (e.g. an extension)?

Comment: Is the rewrite code you posted in apache's `httpd.conf` file, or is it in a `.htaccess` file? And if its in `.htaccess` is that file in the `/downloads` directory or is it in the root? Please clarify your question. Also, which files in `/downloads` are to be handled differently? As it stands, the question is a bit too vague to be accurately answered.

Comment: It is a .htaccess, in /downloads. PHP files need to not be affected (not downloaded). If I can add other file types or specific files later on, great. Sorry for not being clear enough!

Comment: You need to put the line you found in front of the other rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` to forbid matches you don't want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) /downloads?file=$1 [R]
```

(I removed the `L` since it didn't have any use here)

Comment: The top line works great. However, the bottom line creates an infinite loop when I just visit /downloads/. My old version was meant to work when something had the format '\*.\*', as I would know it. A filename AND extension. It seems to be working with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$  RewriteRule ^(.+\.*) /downloads?file=$1 [R,L]`, apart from visiting /downloads/folder. It tries to download the folder.

Comment: Just use `RewriteRule (.*) /downloads.php?file=$1 [R]` to prevent the loop.